# How to group a data frame of countries into regions, calculate the mean of each region, then determine which region has the highest mean?

Tags: r, dataframe

1. This is in R. I am a bit stuck on this. I need to group the countries into their  regions, which I think I understand how to do:

   life_expectancy_split_in_regions <- split(life_expectancy, life_expectancy$region)

[image: This is how the structure of the data frame looks like at this point]

2. Then, I think I need to utilize the "apply" to go through each region and do this function:

   mean_of_regions <- apply(life_expectancy_split_in_regions, function(x) { sapply(x$change, mean)})
3. I think that will get the mean for each region.
4. Then, to compare the different regions to determine which region has the highest "average change of life expectancy": I'm not sure how to do this.

   - There are just a lot of moving parts, it'd be nice if someone could help me solidy my understanding of how it would fit together. I apologize for my amateur coding.

Comment: Please, provide some reproducible example we can work with.

Comment: Hi Pat, how would I do that exactly? I've updated the screenshot of what the dataframe looks like, after it's been grouped by the region. Then, I am trying to access the "change" vector of each region to find the mean of all the countries within that region. Lastly, I am trying to determine which region has the highest mean.

Comment: your screenshot is a screenshot. We need a data (not a screenshot nor an image) like yours and then we can work with to try to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid splitting the table up like that, and instead work with it all together. You need to find the mean change for each region, then identify which region has the highest change.

My personal favourite, `data.table` will work well here:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( life_expectancy )
```

First, grouping the table `by` region, we find the mean change for each region, labelling that column `mean.change`. We then pipe the created table to another function to extract the region with the highest `mean.change` result.

```
life_expectancy[ , .( mean.change = mean( change ) ),
                 by = region
              ][ , region[ which.max( mean.change ) ] ]
```

This should (I can't test, since I don't have your data) output a single region name, corresponding to the highest mean change.

Comment: "Error in `[.data.frame`(life_expectancy, , .(mean.change = mean(change)),  : 
  unused argument (by = region) " What does this error mean?

Comment: did you run the first two lines of code? You need to load the `data.table` package, then make your `data.frame` into a `data.table` before the functions will work. If you don't have `data.table` installed yet, run `install.packages("data.table")` first.

Comment: Thank you, the installation fixed the problem! :) What would the solution look like using sapply, apply, and r's standard functions?

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution with random data since you do not provide sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
life_expectancy <- data.frame(region = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 change = rnorm(100))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
life_expectancy %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarise(mean_change = mean(change)) %>%
  arrange(-mean_change) %>%
  head(n = 1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   region mean_change
#>   <fct>        <dbl>
#> 1 u             1.64
```